# LINQ/EDM cache's efficiency in a webapp

Tags: asp.net, sql, linq, ado.net, linq-to-entities

I was just learning how to use the LINQ/EDM combination to retrieve and update a simple user-thread-and-comment webapp as part of evaluating it.
When I turn on SQL Profiler, I rarely see a SQL statement executed by my app.
I'm starting to really like how well it keeps things cached, coz as soon as I add new data, it magically updates itself while I'm blinking.

But is that something I should be scared of?
My concern is when I use this to make a webapp with some traffic (whatever hit count that reaches this approach's par).
Should I keep a single context object at app-level, so that different sessions can benefit from each other's cache entries?
Or should I do the create-and-release on each page submission?

I know this sounds like an open-ended question, but I really have that as a question:  how does the entity cache its data when using LINQ?

Comment: Scratch what I said about "rarely see a SQL statement".  I was looking at the wrong profile.  There's relatively a bunch of statements per thread-comment request.  To me that's expensive.  So the rest of my question still applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the `ObjectContext` question you should use a lifetime of per-page-request cycle or smaller.  It's designed for a unit of work and not for the application lifetime.  Search SO for "ObjectContext lifetime" or "DataContext lifetime" and you'll see this is a common question.